# First time load does not match path

Tags: angular

This is app.routing.ts - the main routes files

```
const APP_ROUTES: Routes = [
{ path: '', component: SecureComponent, canActivate: [AuthService], children : SECURE_ROUTES}
, { path: '', component: PublicComponent, children : PUBLIC_ROUTES}
```

];

This is secure_routes and public_routes :

```
export const SECURE_ROUTES: Routes = [
{
    path: 'Order', component: OrderOutletComponent,
    children: [
        { path: 'new', component: AddOrder},
        { path: '', component: OrdersComponent},
        {
            path: ':id',
            children: [
                { path: '', component: OrderComponent},
                { path: 'edit', component: EditComponent}
            ]
        }
    ]
},
{ path: 'Dashboard', component: DashboardComponent }];
```

I have loaded the app.routing in my app module - the top level module. 
When I try opening a url for example http://host/Order - the order component does not load and empty page is displayed and the url also changes to http://host/ in the address bar

However http://host/dashboard loads the dashboard component properly.

Comment: Have you tried changing your routes so `{ path: '', component: OrdersComponent},` is placed above  `{ path: 'new', component: AddOrder},`? Order does matter with route definintions.

Comment: Have you tried turning on route tracing to see what's going on?

Comment: @DeborahK I checked it. There is a navigation cancel on the '/Order' route and then navigation starts for '/'. This only happens on load